# jQuery Content Reveal swipe Carousel with Tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, carousel

I have been asked to have a look at creating a carousel for mobile, which requires: -

- Carousel slider to swipe left and right
- Content Carousel (not images)
- Tabs at the top which you can tap and it will slide left / right
- Finally the left and right divs slightly visible showing about 15px off the screen (similar to the facebook app on the feeds when people upload >3 images.

I have attached an image for demonstration purposes.

http://i41.tinypic.com/1qmj51.png

So as you can see the package 1 and 3 are slightly visible to show the user there is more content they can swipe though, and also having the tabs. So as you tab a tab it swipes left or right and the active tab changes?

Are there any plugins out there that does this?

Thanks

Comment: swipe.js is pretty good. It has tabbing ability at the bottom formed as circles but you could style these into buttons and locate them at the top, not dissimilar to your image

Comment: I have found this 2nd from last example, downloaded the code but cant get it working at all http://www.mobify.com/mobifyjs/modules/carousel-examples/ its Nearly what im after

Comment: In what way does it not work? are you ensuring that you have included the jQuery library in the head of the HYML document?

Comment: I am nearly there, however need the packages centered with revealing the left and right packages, when swiped tabs need to change and vise-versa. http://jsfiddle.net/jnYs7/

Comment: edit the left margin, i've added it to an answer below